# In the compilation system, how does linker (ld) know who to link myprogram.o to?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

I recently read the CSAPP and had some doubts about the compilation system part of it.

Now we have a sample using HelloWorld.c(just print hello world). The book said in Pre-processor phase, they replace the "#include " line with the content of this header file. But when I open the stdio.h, I find that there is only a declaration for printf() and there is no concrete implementation. So in the compilation system, when will the specific implementation of printf() be introduced?

And the book also said, in linking phase, the linker(ld) linked helloworld.o and printf.o . Why the linker knows to link my object file to printf.o? In a compilation system, why does it declare this function in the first step(Pre-processor phase) and link the concrete implementation in the last step(linking phase)?

Comment: `printf` is a part of standard library, which is always linked (unless specified otherwise)

Comment: linker links some libraries by default, for example `libc.so` and `libdl.so`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Practically, over-simplified:

- You can compile a function into a library (ex. `.a` or `.so` file on unix).
- The library has a function body (assembly  instructions) and a function name. Ex. the library `libc.so` has `printf` function that starts at character number `0xaabbccdd` in the library file `libc.so`.
- You want to compile your program.
- You need to know what arguments `printf` takes. Does it take `int` ? Does it take `char *`? Does it take `uint_least64_t`? It's in the header file - `int printf(const char *, ...);`. The header tells the compiler how to call the function (what parameters does the function take and what type it returns). Note that each `.c` file is compiled separately.
- The function declaration (what arguments the function takes and what does it return) is not stored in the library file. It is stored in the header (only). The library has function name (only `printf`) and compiled function body. The header has `int printf(const char *, ...);` without function body.
- You compile your program. The compiler generates the code, so that arguments with proper size are pushed onto the stack. And from the stack your code takes variable returned from the function. Now your program is compiled into assembly that looks like `push pointer to "%d\n" on the stack; push some int on the stack; call printf; pop from the stack the returned "int"; rest of the instructions;`.
- Linker searches through your compiled program and it sees `call printf`. It then says: "Och, there is no `printf` body in your code". So then it searches `printf` in the libraries, to see where it is. The linker goes through all the libraries you link your program with and it finds `printf` in the standard library - it's in `libc.so` at address `0xaabbccdd`. So linker substitutes `call printf` for `goto libs.so file to address 0xaabbccdd` kind-of instruction.
- After all "symbols" (ie. function names, variables names) are "resolved" (the linker has found them somewhere), then you can run your program. The `call printf` will jump into the file `libc.so` at specified location.

What I have written above is only for illustration purposes.

Comment: Thank you very mush. It's so clear to me and enough to me for now. ofc I will read related book in the future. So, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

*Why the linker knows to link my object file to printf.o?*

LD knows how to search and find them. You can see the  with man [ld.so](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html):

> If a shared object dependency does not contain a slash, then it is
>   searched for in the following order:
>
> - Using the directories specified in the DT_RPATH dynamic section attribute of the binary if present and DT_RUNPATH attribute does not
>     exist. Use of DT_RPATH is deprecated.
> - Using the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH, unless the executable is being run in secure-execution mode (see below), in which
>     case this variable is ignored.
> - Using the directories specified in the DT_RUNPATH dynamic section attribute of the binary if present. Such directories are searched only
>     to find those objects required by DT_NEEDED (direct dependencies)
>     entries and do not apply to those objects' children, which must
>     themselves have their own DT_RUNPATH entries. This is unlike DT_RPATH,
>     which is applied to searches for all children in the dependency tree.
> - From the cache file /etc/ld.so.cache, which contains a compiled list of candidate shared objects previously found in the augmented
>     library path. If, however, the binary was linked with the -z nodeflib
>     linker option, shared objects in the default paths are skipped. Shared
>     objects installed in hardware capability directories (see below) are
>     preferred to other shared objects.
> - In the default path /lib, and then /usr/lib. (On some 64-bit architectures, the default paths for 64-bit shared objects are /lib64,
>     and then /usr/lib64.) If the binary was linked with the -z nodeflib
>     linker option, this step is skipped.

*In a compilation system, why does it declare this function in the first step(Pre-processor phase) and link the concrete implementation in the last step(linking phase)?*

In the compilation stage, you need to know *what* you're going to link to and compile accordingly, so it needs to read the `.h` files with the definition. In the linking stage, only `.o` files are needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the linker knows to link my object file to printf.o

Because the complier notes this inside what it produces, typically called object files (.o).

> why does it declare this function in the first step ...

To know about it.

> ... and link the concrete implementation in the last step

Because there is no need to do this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

All the C and C++ standards tell you is that you need to `#include` a given header file in order to introduce some functionality (on some platforms that might not even be necessary although inclusion is a good idea since then you're writing *portable* code).

That affords compilers a lot of flexibility.

The linking, if any, will be done automatically. Note that some functions might even be hardcoded into the compiler itself.

Answer (score 0):

By default the library ( containing the implementation of printf ) is linked everytime in your C program.

By including headers you just specify (for the time being) at compile time that the implementations of the declared functions (inside the header) are somewhere else. And later in the linking phase, those function implementations are 'added' in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this mean that not only the declaration of the function but also the concrete implementation's location is included in the header file? So in linking phase, they know which functions need to be link and where to find them?